# Random Variable density function and expected value.

Tags: probability

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrLkw.png)

[image]

Not really sure how to start this problem.

Also, how do I find the expected value? Thanks.

Comment: If you don’t know what $E[\cdot]$ means, consult your text or notes. You won’t get far without that.

Comment: Okay I found out that E[] equal an integral of some x. does this mean that I do the integral of 1/3x^2 or do I do the integral of (Z+3)^2, from [-1,2] and then multiply by 10? Could you tell me what I would need to do. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the integral below,

$$E[(Z+3)^2]=\frac {10}{3}\int_{-1}^2(Z+3)^2 Z^2dZ$$

Comment: So, E[x] = integral of x times the density function right? Sorry if I asked a bad question.

Comment: That is correct